# $\int_{\phi} z^2e^{z^3}\sin z$ dz

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$\int_{\phi}  z^2e^{z^3}\sin z$ dz where  $\phi \in [0, 2pi]$ and $ \phi (t) =e^{4it}$.

I want to use Cauchy's Integral Formuła for Derivtives, but I can't simplify this expression. I use substitution $ z=e^{4it}$ and $dz=ie^{4it}$ dt.

Comment: $z^2e^{z^3}\sin(z)$ is holomorphic in and on the circle $z=e^{i4t}$, $t\in [0,\pi/2]$.  The integral is $0$ by Cauchy's Integral Theorem.

Comment: Do should I use any any another way?

Comment: Why would you want to proceed any other way when the conclusion is immediate here?